# ORACLE SQL : Get instance name as global variable/constant

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to read instance name and set some constant to true if the condition is correct.

For example i have already this

```
--DYNAMICALLY CREATE A PACKAGE TO HOLD CONSTANTS.
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    '
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XXX_COMPILATION_CONSTANTS IS 
    C_MAKE_PUBLIC_XXX_SCHEMA CONSTANT BOOLEAN := '||CASE WHEN USER = 'TEST' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END||';
    END;
    ';
END;
```

How can I read instance name like USER above ?

```
--DYNAMICALLY CREATE A PACKAGE TO HOLD CONSTANTS.
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    '
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XXX_COMPILATION_CONSTANTS IS 
    C_MAKE_PUBLIC_XXX_SCHEMA CONSTANT BOOLEAN := '||CASE WHEN **INSTANCE**= 'MY_TEST_DB' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END||';
    END;
    ';
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you probably don't want to create your own package.  The [`USERENV` context](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm) probably already has all the information you want.

```
sys_context( 'USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER' )
```

for the current user and

```
sys_context( 'USERENV', 'INSTANCE_NAME` )
```

for the name of the instance.  In the documentation I linked to, you can see that there are a bunch of other attributes in that context that are already populated with useful bits of information.

Comment: Thanks but I need that in the package

Comment: @Jeremy - If you really want it in the package, you can use `sys_context( 'USERENV', 'INSTANCE_NAME' )` to get the instance name in your `case` statement.

Comment: thanks. I do not know what i tried but i found online this as well how ever could not compile.  I need it in package cause i use it for conditional compiling. You helped me a lot thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your example works if you use `sys_context('userenv','instance_name')`:

```
begin
    execute immediate
    'create or replace package xxx_compilation_constants as 
    c_make_public_xxx_schema constant boolean := '||
        case
            when sys_context('userenv','instance_name') = 'MY_TEST_DB' then 'TRUE'
            else 'FALSE'
        end||';
    end;
';
end;
```

which creates a package as:

```
create or replace package xxx_compilation_constants as
    c_make_public_xxx_schema constant boolean := FALSE;
    end;
```

However, it would be simpler to define the package statically as:

```
create or replace package xxx_compilation_constants
as
    c_make_public_xxx_schema constant boolean :=
        sys_context('userenv','instance_name') = 'MY_TEST_DB';
end;
```

You might also look at [conditional compilation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/conditional-compilation-10gr2), though I'm not really seeing a use for it in your example.